# Magicknet Get and SET image resolution (PPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, imagemagick, magicknet

I am using Magicknet for image manipulation in my ASP.NET project. How can I Get & SET the image resolution of the image? - When I resize a 300 pixel/inch image it apparently by default result in a 72 pixel/inch image, and because I maintain the same size, I get a very low quality image. So I need to be able to maintain the ppi of the image.

I also want to add that this might result in either magicknet or System.Drawing.Image, but I am not 100% sure.

The code that I'm using:

```
    img.ModulusDepth = 10;   
    img.Compression = CompressionType.JPEGCompression;
    img.Quality = 80;


    string optimizedImage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\temp\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
    img.Write(optimizedImage); // save optimized image as temp file

    Magick.Term();

    System.Drawing.Image tempimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(optimizedImage);  // load the optimized image into an image objec
```

From what [I've read here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#density), the default ias 72 pixels per inch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the MagickImage class `Density` property.

Ex.:

```
magickImageObj.Density = new Density(150, DensityUnit.PixelsPerInch);
```

The Density class has a few other constructor overloads available.

Answer (score -1):

Image DPI is quite irrelevant in the context of the web; it's a metadata setting ignored by all browsers and nearly all printers.

Pixels are the units with which you must work; DPI is a leaky abstraction handled differently by every library and UI.

You might [also consider using a server-safe alternative to Magicknet](http://imageresizing.net).